# Adding items to the WPF UI as they load into an offline MSSQL database

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I am trying to create an asynchronous C# windows application which detects video files on the selected path and then loads their metadata from an external movie database API.
Everything is pretty much done, but I am having trouble with responsively loading the results in the UI as my local database fills up movie by movie.
I am using WPF for the UI, there is only one main window which has a container for a few different user controls (showing all movies, showing the particular clicked movie and a screen for adding new paths).
So when the user adds a path, my code recursively searches for all video files, the list of all corresponding files is returned to the main window from where it's sent to my API which fetches the required metadata and saves it into a local MSSQL database.
Here is my code:

```
private async void AddFilesToDb(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<File> files = (List<File>)sender;
    progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    double addPercentage = 100.0 / (double)files.Count();
    var progress = new Progress<double>(value => progressBar.Value = value);
    ProgramRepository progRepo = new ProgramRepository();
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        double i = addPercentage;
        foreach (File file in files)
        {
            progRepo.CreateVideoMetadata(file);
            ((IProgress<double>)progress).Report(i);
            i += addPercentage;
        }
    });
    progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    ShowMenu(Model.Menu.Videos);
    videosControl.VideosLoader(2);
}
```

Currently I'm only trying to achieve that as the await Task.Run() function completes the user is redirected to a menu where all of the added videos are shown (the last two lines). But videosControl.VideosLoader(2) gets 0 files from the offline database, and when I click on the manual load button:

```
private void btnMovies_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ShowMenu(Model.Menu.Videos);
    videosControl.VideosLoader(2);
}
```

Everything seems to load completely fine.
So my first question is why is the database empty on the first time I try to load it as the await Task.Run() is completed.
And my second and more important question is:
How can I achieve that as one movie is added to the offline DB, it's automatically added to the UI for the user to see, and every next one is added also.
Thank you in advance!

EDIT: here is a picture with that explains the workflow:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQY2L.jpg)

Comment: An offline database is [one that doesn't work and so doesn't lock files or accept connections](https://serverfault.com/questions/201171/why-would-i-take-a-database-offline) during normal operations would be to move the files to a new location.  I assume `offline` was used by mistake. You haven't posted your data access code though, so it's impossible to say what's wrong. Using `Task.Run` with Entity Framework is definitely a sign that something is wrong.

Comment: If `CreateVideoMetadata` writes one record to the database at a time, the operation takes N times longer than a proper EF operation that stored N rows in a single `SaveChanges`. In any case ORMs like EF are the wrong tool for bulk data import. The *correct* tool is to use SqlBulkCopy in code, `bcp` or `BULK INSERT` on the server.

Comment: `async void` methods are only meant for event handlers as they *can't* be awaited. `AddFilesToDb`can't be an event handler because `sender` gets cast to a `List<File>`. Lists [don't have events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8). This method probably throws but the application never notices

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes "offline" was a wrong expression, I meant local database as it's stored locally and not on a remote server.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `CreateVideoMetadata` is a function that fetches movie metadata from tmdb API based on a filename, stores metadata into a Video class which is saved to my database. Yes it fetches one movie's metadata by one and saves one by one. The reason behind that is: I want the UI to be updated as movies are getting saved (e.g. first movie is saved to database and it's automatically shown in the container, same goes for the second one, up until the last one).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `AddFilesToDb` is an event handler which is fired from another User Control as the button "Next" (from the screenshot) is clicked:
`private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddVideosClicked?.Invoke(_files, EventArgs.Empty);
        }`
and `_files` are prepared to be sent in another method of the same user control

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know I'm not a very experienced, this is a task I'm doing for college. But can you make a few suggestions how can I remake this to make it function as intended. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQY2L.jpg
So this is the workflow I'm trying to achieve:
1. User chooses a path on the hard drive to be searched for video files (DONE)
2. Movie names are normalized from fiilenames via regex so I can extract the movie title alone (DONE)
3. `CreateVideoMetadata` fetches movie metadata and saves it to database
4.As each movie is added I want it displayed in the UI for the user to see